# How to launch a bash script in another one?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to launch a script bash from another one using sudo.

Here is my first script 
**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "test.sh" $1 $2 $3  >>/home/pi/test.log
sudo ./temp.sh "$1" "$2" "$3" >>/home/pi/test.log &
echo "test.sh done!" >>/home/pi/test.log
```

When I run

```
./test.sh a b c
```

in my console, it works. The second script is launched with args!
But when the first script is launched from an other tools (Deluge Execute plugin), the second script is never launched. It looks like a problem with permissions.

**Update :**
I rename the second script to **temp.sh** and its make an echo in a second file

```
#!/bin/bash
torrentid=$1
torrentname=$2
torrentpath=$3

echo " Details: " $torrentid $torrentpath $torrentname >> /home/pi/temp.log
```

It works when launched by command line, but not by Deluge.

**Update 2 :**
The second script is voluntary launch in a second shell/env with & because it will make a long action.
I do this because when a script is launched & executed by deluge plugin, deluge is freezed during the execution. So I need a script that launches a second one in background.

**Update 3 :**
my user pi as already `pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` in the visudo file

Comment: Are you sure that Deluge Execute plugin sets the working directory correctly? Since you're referencing sort.sh relatively to the working directory, it may not exist at all.

Comment: Both scripts are in the same folder. If I target sort.sh from deluge, it's works.

Comment: How do you conclude that `sort.sh` doesn't run?  Could you elaborate on that?  Does the last statement, i.e. `echo done` execute?

Comment: sort.sh isn't execute because his job isn't made.
The last echo is executed (wrote in my log file)

Comment: If you put `exec >> /home/pi/temp0.log 2>&1` into your “test.sh”, what do you get in the temp0.log?

Comment: What does this line ?

Comment: It starts sending all output (standard output and error output) from the script to `/home/pi/temp0.log`, except for things that are explicitly redirected elsewhere (and except for programs that force output to the terminal rather than one of the standard streams). This should provide a pretty good approximation of what you would see on the screen if you ran the script on the console or in a window – and so it might show what’s going wrong, that you otherwise can’t see, e.g., an error message from the `sudo` line.

Comment: When you run it from the command line (after just logging in), does **sudo** ask for a password or is this not required?

Comment: The `"test.sh done!"` line will right now be written to the log directly after `test.sh` has forked; not when the command is actually done. You should rather have a second line like: `(sudo ./temp.sh "$1" "$2" "$3" && echo "test.sh done!") >>/home/pi/test.log &`. You still won't be able to provide credentials for `sudo` non-interactively, so you will need to give the Deluge user `sudo` privileges to execute `test.sh` without password authentication for your attempt to work.

Comment: Thanks @DanielAndersson , how can I do this?

Comment: @RaspDealer: You can set such privileges in the `sudo` configuration file via the `visudo` command. Read up on the syntax. There might also be annotated examples and further instructions in the file when it opens.

Answer (score 1):

One definitive problem with

```
sudo ./sort.sh "$1" "$2" "$3" & >>/home/pi/test.log
```

is that you attempt to redirect the output *after* making the script run in background.  Note that `&` acts as a command separator too, so you are essentially executing the following *two* commands:

```
sudo ./sort.sh "$1" "$2" "$3" &
>>/home/pi/test.log
```

You need to fix the *order* of the two.  Say:

```
sudo ./sort.sh "$1" "$2" "$3" >>/home/pi/test.log &
```

---

Another problem is that you specify a relative path for the second script.  Either replace `./temp.sh` in the script with the absolute path or prefix it with the directory containing the script

```
"$(dirname "$0")"/temp.sh
```

Comment: He could group all the commands with `{ ... }` and redirect the output of the group. Or `exec 1>logfile` first.

Comment: @glennjackman True.  It's tough to read into the mind of the OP.  I just pointed to an obvious problem that would cause the redirection to be a _no-op_ that might lead one into thinking that the command isn't being executed.

Comment: Thanks for that but this problem matters without the & too...

Comment: I've just update the post

Comment: Problem persists !

Comment: @RaspDealer You need to fix the path to the second script.  Refer to the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
# rest of script goes here
# ...
```

Comment: Whats does this line ?

Comment: You explicitly invoke `./temp.sh` -- you specify "find temp.sh in the current directory". When you invoke `test.sh`, what is your current directory? Are you in the directory containing `temp.sh`? If not, you'll get an error like `./temp.sh: command not found`. If you (or deluge) calls "/home/raspdealer/bin/test.sh", then your current directory will change to "/home/raspdealer/bin", and then "./temp.sh" will be found.

Comment: Everything is in the same directory.

Comment: That doesn’t matter, @RaspDealer. It’s all about the working directory. Never use relative paths when referring to “fixed” objects.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your BASH code:

1. you use sudo which requires authentification, something Deluge Execute probably can't do (I don't know Deluge.)
2. you use & which explicitly starts your command in a subshell with its own environment.

To fix 1. you have two options. You can either make the Deluge user a sudoer and echo the password into sudo like so `echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S <command>` or you can create an appropriate rule in your sudoers file to allow the Deluge user to run this command without authentication. Read the sudo man-page for more info.

To fix 2. just remove the "&" symbol and consider using the built-in command `source`. Read the BASH man-page for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Modified scripts.
Test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
echo "test.sh $1 $2 $3"  >>/home/pi/test.log
gksu bash ./temp.sh "$1" "$2" "$3" >> /home/pi/test.log &
echo "test.sh done!" >>/home/pi/test.log
```

temp.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
torrentid="$1"
torrentname="$2"
torrentpath="$3"

echo "Details:  $torrentid $torrentpath $torrentname" >> /home/pi/temp.log
```

If `gksu` not available use `pkexec`

## comments

`gksu` is the graphical frontend of `sudo`. Just try `sudo gedit` and   `gksu gedit`. Sudo removed from the newer version of Ubuntu.  Did you tried the script ? How is it ?

## 2

try 1: add `sleep 15` at the end of first script, test.sh.
Try 2: add `nohup` before gksu. Ie `nohup gksu bash ...`

Comment: Whats does `gksu bash` and `pkexec bach` ?

Comment: I've got this message "Refusing to render service to dead parents." when I launch it manually

Answer (score 0):

Another issue is that two commands
(`sudo ./temp.sh "$1" "$2" "$3"` and `echo "test.sh done!"`) are
writing to the same file (`/home/pi/test.log`) concurrently (i.e., simultaneously),
because the `temp.sh` (if it runs) has the file open in the background when the `echo` executes. 
This shouldn’t be a major problem – it shouldn’t prevent `temp.sh` from running –
but if you do solve the primary problem and get `temp.sh` to run, and it writes output,
then it will probably overwrite the `"test.sh done!"` message. 
Conversely, if `temp.sh` runs quickly enough,
then the `echo` could possibly overwrite the first 14 bytes of output from `temp.sh`.

Comment: I'm ok with that but my sure that `./temp.sh` wille take few minutes. I just need to export this 'action' in an other script to release the first one.